# Model to create slider from bootstrap 4 IN DJANGO

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I created the slider with bootstrap 4.
Now I want to get it from admin upload images. I have h1 and h3 tag also.
How can I manage this with admin?
How can I work with media?

```html
{% block content2 %}


<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <!-- <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/background.png" alt="First slide"> -->
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static "blog/images/background.png" %}" alt="not found">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1 class="display-4">Welcome to igyaan.co.in</h1>
          <h3>Python Developer</h3>
           <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">View Demo</button> -->
          <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">Get Started</button> -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="">Get Started</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <!-- <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/background.png" alt="Second slide"> -->
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static "blog/images/background.png" %}" alt="not found">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1 class="display-4">Welcome to igyaan.co.in</h1>
          <h3>Python Developer</h3>
           <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">View Demo</button> -->
          <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#exampleModal"
          data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Get Started</button> -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="">Get Started</button>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please flesh out question. " how can i work with media" is far too broad -- check out Django help pages: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/

Comment: I have done this on my own thanks followed the document